# The type or namespace name AsyncLocal<> could not be found

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am trying to integrate some code in my project. There is this AsyncLocal object.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

...

private readonly AsyncLocal<bool> callbackExecutionInProgress;
```

Produces compiler error: Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'AsyncLocal<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I have found nothing on google about this problem. According to Microsoft this should be defined in System.Threading, but referencing that namespace does not help. 
Is there something else I have to do?

.Net = 4.7.02558

Comment: What .NET Framework version are you targeting? Is it 4.6 or later? (or any of the others mentioned in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=netframework-4.7.1#applies-to)

Comment: _"my compiler cannot recognise that AsyncLocal"_ - read [ask], show the actual compiler error and share your research.

Comment: It's not an object.  It's a type.  You're declaring a variable of that type that an object of that type could be assigned to. As suggested, you should always go to the documentation first. If you haven't imported the required namespace, referenced the required assembly or targeted a required .NET version then you're not going to be able to use that type.

Comment: I have referenced System.Threading which is the required namespace. Do I have to manually reference some assemblies? The .net version should be alright I think.

Answer (score 2):

Problem fixed.
It was indeed the wrong version of the Framework. When I go in the menue bar to Help->About Microsoft Visual Studio, it says that .NET Framework version is 4.7.02558. But in the project file it said v4.5.2. This is somehow contradictory.

I changed the version to 4.6.1 now it works.